# Build spring-boot from sources failed with UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.sslRestrictedProtocolsECDHETLS1Failure

Tags: spring-boot

For tests on correctness and performance of our development environment  we build **SpringBoot 1.4.1-RELEASE** from sources.
we had cloned VM with same jdk,tools, and springboot sources version.
we building it on JDK 1.8.0_102 and maven 3.3.9 versions.
On one of our VMs build was unfortunately failed on test phase with next error:   tests in error: **UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.sslRestrictedProtocolsECDHETLS1Failure**

```
@Test(expected = SSLHandshakeException.class)
        public void sslRestrictedProtocolsECDHETLS1Failure() throws Exception {
            testRestrictedSSLProtocolsAndCipherSuites(new String[] { "TLSv1" },
                    new String[] { "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" });
        }
```

the error is next:

---

### Test set: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests

```
Tests run: 66, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.666 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests
sslRestrictedProtocolsECDHETLS1Failure(org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests)  Time elapsed: 0.2 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException> but was<java.net.SocketException>
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:91)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.getClientResponse(AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.getResponse(AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.java:982)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.getResponse(AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.java:976)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.testRestrictedSSLProtocolsAndCipherSuites(AbstractEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.java:645)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.sslRestrictedProtocolsECDHETLS1Failure(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactoryTests.java:230)
```

thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what can be wrong on same configurations? only with one test case?